# How to access Salesforce data through CData ODBC driver using python with using Salesforce Access Token of the user from OAuth autherization?

Tags: python, salesforce, odbc, pyodbc, cdata-drivers

I have a web application and I want to integrate Salesforce to that. So when the OAuth2 authorization happens from the user side(he logs in and give access for our application to access his data). After the user gives access I will be getting the below mentioned parameters.

```
access_token
refresh_token
instance_url
issued_at
signature
scope
token_type
```

Using the above parameter, I should get the data through Salesforce API via CData using python3. So how do I do that through CData is my question. I hope I am making sense till here. I have gone through the document which you have sent. I am unable to understand. Can you please elaborate?

I found only one document connecting through python mentioned below. It does not contain about using access token.
http://cdn.cdata.com/help/RFE/odbc/pg_odbclangpythonconnect.htm

I gone through the CData documents related to Salesforce I didn't get how to do. I should not use username, passowrd, client id, client secret. Can anyone help me out in this.

Answer (score 0):

The instructions for connecting to Salesforce using OAuth with the CData ODBC Driver are here: http://cdn.cdata.com/help/RFE/odbc/pg_oauthcustomappcreate.htm (copied below).

---

#### Authenticate to Salesforce from a Web Application

To obtain the access token, set the following connection properties:

- **OAuthClientId**: Set to the consumer key in your app settings.
- **OAuthClientSecret**: Set to the consumer secret in your app settings.
- **CallbackURL**: Set to the callback URL in your app settings.

When connecting via a web application, or if the driver is not authorized to open a browser window, you need to exchange temporary verification values for the access token:

1. Call GetOAuthAuthorizationUrl. The stored procedure returns the URL to the OAuth endpoint.
2. Log in and authorize the application. You are redirected back to the callback URL. If you set the GrantType parameter to Implicit, the callback URL contains the **OAuthAccessToken** and **OAuthServerUrl** in a query string parameter. If you set the GrantType parameter to code, the callback URL contains the verifier code in the query string parameter named "code". Extract the verifier code and call GetOAuthAccessToken.

#### *The relevant part:*

To connect to data, set the following connection properties:

- **OAuthAccessToken**
- **OAuthServerUrl**

To automatically refresh the access token when it expires, set **InitiateOAuth** to *REFRESH* and set **OAuthRefreshToken**. Alternatively, call the RefreshOAuthAccessToken stored procedure when the access token expires. Given a refresh token as input, the procedure returns a valid OAuth access token.

As an alternative to retrieving the authorization URL and having the user log in to Salesforce, you can set up a password grant type by calling GetOAuthAccessToken, setting GrantType to PASSWORD. Here, you need to ensure that the user name and password are both set in the connection string, in addition to the client ID and secret of your application. Note that InitiateOAuth must be set to OFF for the password grant type to work. You cannot refresh the token obtained this way. This method has the advantage of removing the login step for users that cannot open a web browser, but it has the disadvantage of the user's credentials being exchanged in plain text between the server and Salesforce.

**Note**: You can configure the session timeout in Salesforce by navigating to Setup > Administration Setup > Security Controls > Session Settings.